# Creating spherical meshes with Direct x?

Tags: c++, directx, mesh

How do you go about creating a sphere with meshes in Direct-x?  I'm using C++ and the program will be run on windows, only.

Everything is currently rendered through an IDiRECT3DDEVICE9 object.

Comment: My answer should do well then, let me know if you need help getting it to work.

Comment: wonderful, i will check this out :)  upvoted for now.  i am unable to test this code until the morning.  If I leave you a comment if this does not work, will you be able to respond at all?

Comment: Yeah, every time I get on (which is frequent), I check all the questions and answers I left comments on for replies. You can of course leave your comment on my answer, and I'll be notified automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`D3DXCreateSphere`](http://doc.51windows.net/Directx9_SDK/?url=/directx9_sdk/graphics/reference/d3dx/functions/shape/d3dxcreatesphere.htm) function.

Comment: So I've done this and I feel that it was working (in blind faith), however, it would not have a texture to it, correct?  Upon the flurry of other things being displayed at the same time, I do not see anything.  Can I add a texture to this?  Or how can I ensure that it has dispalyed correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure if `D3DXCreateSphere` generates texture coordinates. There is a tutorial here [1] that demonstrates how to do so. [1] http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/spheremap.htm

Comment: I think that regardless I'm gonna run into problems with the CreateSphere function going into that fail-if statement, no?

Comment: Actually, I think if it returns 0 then it succeeded. Try using the `FAILED` macro. (Or: `if (/* create sphere */ != D3D_OK)`

Comment: You're correct, I've checked the HRESULT and it seems to have succeeded.  Not sure why it followed into that loop then.  Cool, thanks!  I'll keep doing my research with it :)

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of ways to create a sphere.

One is to use polar coordinates to generate slices of the sphere.

```
struct Vertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    float nx, ny, nz;
};
```

Given that struct you'd generate the sphere as follows (I haven't tested this so I may have got it slightly wrong).

```
std::vector< Vertex > verts;
int count   = 0;
while( count < numSlices )
{
    const float phi = M_PI / numSlices;
    int count2  = 0;
    while( count2 < numSegments )
    {
        const float theta   =  M_2PI / numSegments
        const float xzRadius = fabsf( sphereRadius * cosf( phi ) );

        Vertex v;
        v.x = xzRadius * cosf( theta );
        v.y = sphereRadius * sinf( phi );
        v.z = xzRadius * sinf( theta );

        const float fRcpLen = 1.0f / sqrtf( (v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y) + (v.z * v.z) );
        v.nx    = v.x * fRcpLen;
        v.ny    = v.y * fRcpLen;
        v.nz    = v.z * fRcpLen;

            verts.push_back( v );
        count2++;
    }
    count++;
}
```

This is how D3DXCreateSphere does it i believe. Of course the code above does not form the faces but thats not a particularly complex bit of code if you set your mind to it :)

The other, and more interesting in my opinion, way is through surface subdivision.

If you start with a cube that has normals defined the same way as the above code you can recursively subdivide each side.  Basically you find the center of the face.  Generate a vector from the center to the new point.  Normalise it.  Push the vert out to the radius of the sphere as follows (Assuming v.n* is the normalised normal):

```
v.x = v.nx * sphereRadius;
v.y = v.ny * sphereRadius;
v.z = v.nz * sphereRadius;
```

You then repeat this process for the mid point of each edge of the face you are subdividing.

Now you can split each face into 4 new quadrilateral faces.  You can then subdivide each of those quads into 4 new quads and so on until you get to the refinement level you require.

Personally I find this process provides a nicer vertex distribution on the sphere than the first method.

Comment: My apologies, this is my first time doing this type of programming.  You're throwing around a lot of math that I simply do not understand, could you possibly elaborate a bit?

Comment: what would you like me to elaborate upon?